# Angularjs directive with ng-repeat and ajax

Tags: angularjs, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive which links to a jquery ticker plugin call. Inside the directive i have some elements repeating for the plugin to cycle through. The data in the elements itself is containing from an ajax request.

Here is the code

```
myApp.directive('vTicker', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

return {

    link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
        $timeout(function () {
           // console.log($(iElm).html());
           $(iElm).vTicker($scope.$eval(iAttrs.vTicker));            
        }, 0);
    }
};
}]);
```

And here is the element

```
<div id="newsticker" v-ticker="{speed: 400,pause: 6000}">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
             <li class="news-item" ng-repeat="newsItem in news">
                 <a href="http://www.nasdaqdubai.com/trading/disclosure-detail?itemID="{{newsItem.id}} target="_blank">{{newsItem.issuer}} : {{newsItem.headline}}</a>
              </li> 
       </ul>
```

The problem is when the directive renders, the ng-repeat hasnt completed rendering. $timeout is not helping either as the content is coming from an ajax call in the controller.

Any help? I want the directive to wait rendering until the controller get the data and ng-repeat render the content in the dom.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the items get added to `news` array. What you need to do is watch on the `news` array and see when it gets filled and then apply your ticker. 
Your current directive definition does not create a new scope so the `news` array would be accessible so yo can do something like

```
link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
   $scope.$watch("news", function(newValue,oldValue) {
       if(newValue && newValue.length > 0) {
        $timeout(function () {
           // console.log($(iElm).html());
           $(iElm).vTicker($scope.$eval(iAttrs.vTicker));            
           }, 0);
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Now if you reassign your `news` array this watch would fire. You can pass the `news` array using isolated scope too.